# searching for space separated words in Elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-query

my data is,

```
POST index_name/_doc/1
{
          "created_date" : "2023-02-09T13:21:41.632492",
          "created_by" : "hats",
          "data" : [
                        {
              "name" : "west cost",
              "document_id" : "1"
            },
            {
              "name" : "mist cost",
              "document_id" : "2"
            },
            {
              "name" : "cost",
              "document_id" : "3"
            }
          ]
        }
```

i used query_String to search

```
GET index_name/_serach
{
    "query_string": {
       "default_field": "data.name",
        "query": "*t cost"
    }
}
```

expected result was:
west cost, mist cost

but the output was:
west cost, mist cost, cost

i have tried many search query but still couldn't find a solution

which search query is used to handle the space, i need to search for the similar patterned value in the field

Comment: There is 1 document, and this document will match your query. So, you are expecting in this document to see 2 address inside the data, right? In the result 1 document will return but data array will have 2 object.

Answer (score 0):

elasticsearch will return you the documents that satisfy the query, and your document `1` does satisfy the query, i.e., there is at least one item in the `data` array that has a name ending by `*t cost`. If you want only the first two `data` items to be returned in your response, you need to index each item independently in a separated document